# I am getting p value 0 for my population I teven tried zscore for normalization

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, statistics, model-selection

## a1 is the columncolumn

a1
g=scipy.stats.mstats.zscore(a1)
g
stat, p = normaltest(g)
print "%.3f, %.9f" %(stat ,p)

**Result  8.570, 0.00000000**

p1=scipy.stats.kstest(g,'norm')
p1

**KstestResult(statistic=1.0, pvalue=0.0)**

h1=scipy.stats.kstest(k, 'poisson',args=(1,))
h1

statistic=0.58, pvalue=0.0

Comment: It's not very clear what you are doing could you try and format it better?